# The list in store app development C++ how to convert to textblock?

Tags: c++, windows

I am try to create store apps in visual studio 2013.
I have some problem during i am doing list.
How to convert en to string value and showing to textblock?

```
list <string> c1;

//Insert Data
c1.push_back("one");
c1.push_back("two");
c1.push_back("three");
c1.push_back("Four");
c1.push_back("Five");
c1.push_back("Six");
c1.push_back("Seven");
c1.push_back("Eight");
c1.push_back("Nine");
c1.push_back("Ten");

//Random data from list

int RandNum = 0 + (std::rand() % 10);

auto en = c1.begin();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get to the `RandNum`-th element as follows:

```
auto iterator = c1.begin();
std::advance(iterator, RandNum);

std::cout << "random num: " << *iterator << '\n';
```

See if running [here](http://ideone.com/nuuUnM).

Comment: I have try...but it cannot work. it shows "auto" type cannot deduce

Comment: Hi I am using visual studio 2013, and I am using it to develop windows 8.1 apps.

Comment: Actually I can use auto type in vs..but when i type code like you give me...it shows the error...